# Let $f:X \to Y$ be a quotient map and $g: Y \to Z$, $g \circ f$ continuous. Show that $g$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, quotient-spaces

> Let $f:X \to Y$  be a quotient map and $g: Y \to Z$, $g \circ f$ continuous. Show that $g$ is continuous.

Let $U$ be open in $Z$ now to show that $g$ is continuous I have to show that $g^{-1}[U]$ is open in $Y$. I have that $$g^{-1}[U]=f[(g \circ f)^{-1}[U]] = f[f^{-1}[g^{-1}[U]]]$$ and since $(g \circ f)$ is continuous the set $(g \circ f)^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$. So I would need that $f$ is an open in order for this to work, but the quotient maps are not neccessarily open. Is the problem statement missing this info or is there another approach?

Comment: $$V\subseteq_\text{open} Z$$$$\implies (g\circ f)^{-1}(V)\subseteq_\text{open} X\text{ as }g\circ f\text{ continuous}$$$$\implies f^{-1}\big(g^{-1}(V)\big)=(g\circ f)^{-1}(V)\subseteq_\text{open} X$$$$\implies\text{Quotient Map}^{-1}(\text{set})=\text{Open}$$$$\implies\text{set}=\text{Open, by definition}$$$$\implies g^{-1}(V)\subseteq_\text{open} Y$$$$\implies g\text{ is continuous as }V\text{ is arbitrary open subset of }Z.$$

Comment: Note that, $f$ being a quotient map, $V \subseteq Y$ is open in $Y$ iff $f^{-1}[V]$ is open in $X$. Thus, $g^{-1}[U]$ is open in $Y$ because...

Answer (score 2):

Let $U \subset Z$ be open.

Then $g^{-1}[U]$ is open $Y$ iff $f^{-1}[g^{-1}[U]]$ is open in $X$ as $f$ is quotient.

Now note that $f^{-1}[g^{-1}[U]] = (g \circ f)^{-1}[U]$ and draw your conclusions...